# PHP Clever script to stop website advertising

Tags: php, replace

At the moment I am currently stopping my users from using certain words by doing this:

```
$badsite = array ("website1", "website2")
$countsite = count($badsite); 
for ($var = 0; $var < $countsite; $var++ ) 
{ 
$tekst = eregi_replace($badsite[$var], 'Word Forbidden', $tekst); 
} 
return $tekst; 
}
```

So if they type one of the words it will be replaced with "Word Forbidden".

But they are getting around it by leaving spaces or symbols or bb codes. 
Would anyone know how I could stop this?

Comment: increase the bad words array to use the symbols / spaces ....

Comment: I believe its no good for you. I can write "seks" instead of "sex" or write "s*e*k*s" or whatever I want. Better approach would be peer review and karma stats...

Comment: But some BB codes have letters in them?

Comment: I agree with @PavelJanicek. The only way to stop this is to tell your users to stop it...

Comment: As a side note: eregi_replace() is deprecated since php 5.3.0. Use preg_replace() instead.

Comment: If it was that easy it I wouldn't have this question.

Comment: This could be [clbuttic](https://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&gs_nf=1&cp=4&gs_id=n&xhr=t&q=clbuttic&pf=p&sclient=psy-ab&oq=clbu&aq=0&aqi=g1g-s1g2&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=5aebd05a57a4c016&biw=1920&bih=930)!!

Answer (score 0):

You're using `eregi_replace` but not passing [regular expressions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regex.examples.php).  That's the next step up in your arms race.

Answer (score 0):

[eregi functions have been deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eregi.php) you're better off not using them, if you do use them at least pass a regex in the first arg and not a string.

Not sure of the purpose of the count-for-loop thing - I'm guessing javascript is your primary language :). If you **do** write a loop just use:

```
foreach($badsite as $value) {
    // $value is "website1";
}
```

you can use code like this:

```
$patterns = '/\b(website1|website2|forbidden\s+fruits?)\b/i';
$cleaned = preg_replace($patterns, '****', $input);
```

The above patterns will replace:

```
* website1
* wEbSiTe1
* website2
* wEbSiTe2
* forbidden fruits
* forbiDDen      fruits
* forbidDen fruit
* etc.
```

Using regexes in a loop is a quite a waste - use use a pipe (|) and concatenate multiple patterns.

Comment: What is this part? forbidden\s+fruits?/i

Comment: @DareHam oh dear - it's an example regex - a pattern describing what to replace.

Comment: Loop is just in case their are more than just one on the same page.

Comment: So I have to type everything a user might use? :|

Comment: @DareHam what? I think the questions you have are more than you've currently asked. The code you are using is obviously different than the code you put in the question then - the code in the question won't work (has parse errors, is incomplete) and the loop doesn't do anything in particular to address multiple occurances of the same string/pattern - all matches are replaced the first time the eregi_replace function is called.

Comment: it contains 2 simple and very obvious parse errors https://gist.github.com/eec3579b8151a19fac8b . Anyway - good luck :)